# Concurrent data structure for multiple producer consumer where every consumer reads each datum

Tags: data-structures, concurrency, queue, lock-free

I need to build the data structure for following scenarios.

1. There are multiple producer, who need to send data to consumers.
2. There are multiple consumers , who need to receive data from producers

So far, this is very typical use case of mpmc queue. However, I have one more constraints.

3. Every consumer must be able to read every data sent by Producer.

Of course, some consumer must be able to read second or third element while other consumer read first one, and if every consumer finish to read the first element, first element should be dropped.

Is there any known data structure for this case?

Comment: Is the number of consumers constant for the duration of the queue?  It might work to have producers add elements with a count element, and each reader that reaches this element must decrement the read-count.  If it was the last one (fetch_add(-1) returns 0), it's responsible for advancing a last_reader position counter (in a circular buffer).  And maybe you'd also have a first_reader position counter?  Maybe each reader would have its own read counter, that it checks against the write position.  Yeah, only the last_reader aka all_done position is what writer need to care about.

Comment: Maybe you don't even need a last_reader position, with that being indicated by sequence numbers and/or atomic counters inside an element being 0 or not.  I suspect this might be *easier* than the standard MPMC case where you need each element to be read exactly once; here each reader can just be independent of others, not having to claim an entry to exclude other readers from it.

Comment: Thanks! Adding to your count approach, I think I can make nice DS using garbage collector and linked list!

Comment: Cool.  If it works out, you could post an answer with some code and/or a summary of the ideas.  Feel free to quote or paraphrase my comments.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe Apache Kafka meet your goal.

Comment: Which part of Kafka?  I googled, it looks like a big framework, not a collection of algorithms you could easily use separately.  If there's some specific feature it has that does this, at least name it and link the documentation for it.